# looking for quote from tanach about good character

Tags: tanach, quotations

What is a pasuk from tanach that can be used to describe a person being intelligent and/or possessing positive character traits?

Comment: If you specifically want a quote discussing both, there is Jeremiah (9:22-3): 
(כב) כֹּ֣ה׀ אָמַ֣ר יְקֹוָ֗ק אַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֤ל חָכָם֙ בְּחָכְמָת֔וֹ וְאַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֥ל הַגִּבּ֖וֹר בִּגְבֽוּרָת֑וֹ אַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֥ל עָשִׁ֖יר בְּעָשְׁרֽוֹ:
(כג) כִּ֣י אִם־בְּזֹ֞את יִתְהַלֵּ֣ל הַמִּתְהַלֵּ֗ל הַשְׂכֵּל֘ וְיָדֹ֣עַ אוֹתִי֒ כִּ֚י אֲנִ֣י יְקֹוָ֔ק עֹ֥שֶׂה חֶ֛סֶד מִשְׁפָּ֥ט וּצְדָקָ֖ה בָּאָ֑רֶץ כִּֽי־בְאֵ֥לֶּה חָפַ֖צְתִּי נְאֻם־יְקֹוָֽק: ס. 22 :

Comment: "Thus saith the LORD: Let not the wise man glory in his wisdom, neither let the mighty man glory in his might, let not the rich man glory in his riches; (23)  But let him that glorieth glory in this, that he understandeth, and knoweth Me, that I am the LORD who exercise mercy, justice, and righteousness, in the earth; for in these things I delight, saith the LORD." See Radak (there) who explains that "knowing God" refers to imitating him by doing kindness and righteousness. This would seem to include proper proper character traits which are being compared to intelligence.

Comment: Do you mean that a person should possess good character (whatever you mean by "good") or verses describing actual people who had them. There are many for both.

Comment: Perhaps, start with *Pirkei Avot* esp. with Rabbeinu Yona's explanation. I suggest that route, b/c frequently, Rabbeinu Yonah cites verses from Mishlei (Proverbs) to support his explanation o fthe Mishnah. That way, you gain a better sense of relevance, rather than "randomly" viewing Mishlei. Many verses in Mishlei can seem quite obscure.

Answer (score 1):

I would look through Proverbs and maybe Ecclesiastes, but I can't think of anything offhand.

However, if it's a woman there's all of אשת חיל; 
specifically Proverbs (Mishlei) 31, verse 26

She openeth her mouth with wisdom; and the law of kindness is on her tongue.

פִּיהָ, פָּתְחָה בְחָכְמָה;    וְתוֹרַת חֶסֶד, עַל-לְשׁוֹנָהּ.